# Account for group age differences

Tags: anova, confounding, matching, propensity-scores

I have a dataset of two patient and one healthy control group which I would like to compare (using R) with respect to a continuous outcome variable (each subjects is measured once). However the groups differ in age. In the context of the dataset the age effect is not of interest. My questions are:

- What is the best way to account for the potentially confouding effect of age?
- From what I know one could do this by either adding it as a covariate in the linear model or matching the samples with respect to age via usage of the propensity score. Which method is recommended in which context?
- Is there an function to select subsamples of each group while matching groups with respect to age?

Answer (score 1):

Michael Posner wrote an interesting paper comparing propensity score matching  with regression adjustment and a third technique using instrumental variables.  The propensity score matching approach worked impressively in his examples.  I will try to get you a link to the paper.